# Цикл при вводе числа не сразу выводит нужную информацию

Tags: java

Цикл работает как то не правильно и при вводе числа не сразу выводит нужную информацию

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i;
    String s;
    do {
        i = sc.nextInt();
        // Бинарный формат числа
        String convert = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        System.out.println(convert + " = двоичноe знвчение");
        sb.append(convert + " = двоичноe знвчение").append("\n");

        // Восьмиричная форма
        convert = Integer.toOctalString(i);
        System.out.println(convert + " = восьмеричное значение");
        sb.append(convert + " = восьмеричное значение").append("\n");;

        // Шеснадцатиричная форма
        convert = Integer.toHexString(i).toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(convert + " = шетнадцатиричное значение");
        sb.append(convert + " = шетнадцатиричное значение").append("\n");;
        s = sc.next();
    } while (!s.equalsIgnoreCase("end"));
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Comment: А какая информация нужна?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно Вы хотели сделать не так, вы в цикле читаете сначала число а потом строку, потом повторяете операцию.

Осмелюсь предположить что Вы хотели сделать иначе, считывать ввод и определять, если там число - печатать его представления в других системах исчисления, а если было введено `"end"` - завершить программу.

Я немного изменил Ваш код:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;
        String s;
        do {
            s = sc.next(); // считываем введенную строку
            try {
                i = Integer.parseInt(s); // пытаемся привести его к Integer

                // сюда мы попадем если приведение прошло успешно

                // Бинарный формат числа
                String convert = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
                System.out.println(convert + " = двоичноe знвчение");
                sb.append(convert + " = двоичноe знвчение").append("\n");

                // Восьмиричная форма
                convert = Integer.toOctalString(i);
                System.out.println(convert + " = восьмеричное значение");
                sb.append(convert + " = восьмеричное значение").append("\n");

                // Шеснадцатиричная форма
                convert = Integer.toHexString(i).toUpperCase();
                System.out.println(convert + " = шетнадцатиричное значение");
                sb.append(convert + " = шетнадцатиричное значение").append("\n");
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
                // сюда мы попадем если введена строка, а не число
            }
        } while (!s.equals("end"));

        System.out.println(sb);
    }
```

Я специально изменил код по минимуму, чтобы было легче увидеть разницу

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил такой вариант с защитой от неправильного формата вводимых данных:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Primer{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Введите целое число.\n"+
        "Для выхода из программы введите \"end\"");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i;
    String str;
    while(scan.hasNext()){

        if(scan.hasNextInt()){
            i = scan.nextInt();
            // Бинарный формат числа
            String convert = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
            System.out.println(convert + " = двоичноe значение");

            // Восьмеричная форма
            convert = Integer.toOctalString(i);
            System.out.println(convert + " = восьмеричное значение");

            // Шеснадцатиричная форма
            convert = Integer.toHexString(i).toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(convert + " = шестнадцатиричное значение");

        }     
        else{
            str = scan.next();
            if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) break; 
            else{
                System.out.println("Неправильный формат данных.\n" +
                    "Необходимо ввести целое число.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nВведите целое число.\n"+
        "Для выхода из программы введите \"end\"");
    }
}
}
```